# why won't this function print what it's supposed to

Tags: python, arrays, return, boolean

```
def straightCheck(playerHand):
    playerHand.sort()
    print(playerHand)
    for i in range(len(playerHand)-1):
            if playerHand[i] != playerHand [i+1] - 1:
                handstrength = 0
                return False
                break
            else:
                handstrength = 5
                return True
    print(handstrength)

x = [5,2,3,4,1]
straightCheck(x)
```

I'm very new to programming and i've not yet mastered the `return` command. This function will work fine without the returns but once I put them in, `playerHand` will continue to print but `handstrength` will not.

Comment: what is the function supposed to do?

Comment: identify an an array contains only consecutive numbers @Padraic

Comment: Do you want to use the  `handstrength` variable?

Comment: Yes, I use it when I call straightCheck in a later function

Comment: Then I would not return booleans, I would http://pastebin.com/S7ii8UcV, any if test will behave exactly the same as `if 0` will evaluate to False and `if 5` will evaluate to True so you get the same behaviour and return the actual values you want to use. setting `handstrength = 5` is just setting the value in the  local scope of the function so those variables are completely pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def straightCheck(playerHand):
    playerHand.sort()
    print(playerHand)
    for i in range(len(playerHand)-1):
        if playerHand[i] != playerHand[i+1] - 1:
            handstrength = 0
            print(handstrength)
            return False
    handstrength = 5
    print(handstrength)
    return True
```

A `return` instruction *terminates* the execution of a function, that means that no code *after* it will ever execute. So if you need to print something, do so before returning. Also, that `break` was unnecessary, as a `return` will not only exit from the loop, it will exit from the whole function.

There's a nastier bug lurking, though. Notice that you only should exit from the function if the check fails, otherwise you must keep looping. We'll be sure that the hand is valid only *after* we exit the loop, so that part of the logic must be *outside* the loop.

Comment: I wonder.. what's the point in looping, if it always returns on the first cycle